# Apache is not multithreaded?

Tags: multithreading, apache

I'm using Apache lounge over 3 month on localhost.
Today I found that my Apache/PHP installation is not multi threaded by running a script that uses sleep(10) & opening 2 browser tabs at same time. (second tab loads 10 seconds after first one was done).

I've installed Apache(apache.org version) and nothing changed.
I'm using PHP 5.3.6 VC9 thread safe.

What is the problem?

Comment: This is a pretty flawed test. In the typical PHP session-based site you'll just be waiting until the session file gets released by prior script. That says nothing about Apache internals.

Comment: Of course Apache HTTP is multithreaded, but aspects of PHP may not be.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure you are using Apache's worker MPM, rather than the prefork one. Depending on your installation, you may simply be able to symbolically link /usr/sbin/httpd2 to /usr/sbin/httpd2-worker (or wherever it is installed).

Of course, in your case, you could also just increase the number of maximum processes in your config, which should enable you to open multiple tabs and have them run at the same time.

Something like this:

```
StartServers       2
MinSpareServers    2
MaxSpareServers    8
ServerLimit        8
MaxClients         8
KeepAlive off
```

Comment: thank you Gabriel, I've changed this setting before asking the question, but nothing changed.

How can I switch to MPM?

Comment: If you successfully increased the max number of apache processes, that should have solved your problem, changing to multithreaded MPM should not even make any difference. Can you post the relevant apache config?

Comment: Another possibility is that you are using MySql with myisam tables, when one query is running on a table, the whole table gets locked, so that other processes/threads that need access to that table have to wait. Switching to innodb tables in MySql should solve that.

Comment: No, in my test file there is not anything but: "<?php sleep(10); ?>

I've also installed latest version of apache & php. even installed WAMP Server. Also added your suggested options, but nothing changed.

Here is my httpd.conf:http://www.mediafire.com/?fckfzb5003ledb9

Comment: From the log it seems the server is already multithreaded, so that's not the problem.

Comment: So, what is the problem?
I'm getting crazy.

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue now. Did you solve somehow? I'm also getting crazy, it always waits for current response and then executes the another. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you stumble upon a browser feature: 
Background tabs are only loaded when you switch to that tab; it is the current default to many browsers (check your settings or use two different browsers to check).
Regards :-)

Comment: He said the 2nd tab loads 10 seconds after the first one, so probably not.