# How to give more memory to Apache

Tags: php, algorithm, apache, cpu

I am using PHP with Apache 2.4 on Centos 7 to run a very CPU intensive probabilistic model. It took 8 days to run it on my home computer so I decided to move it in to a Cloud service. So I configured it and now it takes only 5 hours. Great!

BUT there is a problem, while processing the algorithm I checked the "free" and "top" command on the Cloud and it reported being using around 24% of my CPU and 10% of the available memory! I am paying around $ 1.50 per hour to a server at Linode with 96 GB and 20 CPU cores, so I it would be better to use 100% of the available CPU.

I know it depends A LOT on the algorithm, but check this code below. It is a very heavy CPU intensive algorithm, and it should use 100% of CPU but no, it uses only 24% (according to "top").

```
<?php

set_time_limit(0);
ini_set("memory_limit","-1");

for ($i=0;$i<10000;$i++) {

    for ($ii=0;$ii<10000;$ii++) {

        for ($iii=0;$iii<10000;$iii++) {

            for ($iiii=0;$iiii<10000;$iiii++) {



            }

        }

    }

}

?>
```

So, what is going on? How can I make my Apache use more CPU and memory?

Comment: what are you doing inside the inner loop? you might very well be waiting for the rest of the system to catch up - e.g. waiting for disk, or waiting for memory to get allocated, blah blah blah. none of that would count against PHP since it's OS kernel internals that'd be holding things up.

Comment: I'll bet it's operating on a very large array (or other chunk of data) which is being swapped in and out of memory.  If that's the case, you could get better performance by adding more memory.  A more sophisticated solution would be to process the data in chunks that fit within memory.

Comment: Hi, I am doing nothing inside the inner loop, this example is just to show you how to simulate this problem. I am 100% sure that if you run the code above in your cloud service or on your apache+php you will not see your CPU go over 24% for same weirdness of apache not allowing more cpu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running a highly CPU-intensive algorithm in PHP? I'm not sure that's such a great idea.

In any case, I think the problem here is that your code is running on a quad-core processor, but only in a single thread. So the maximum CPU usage you can currently achieve is 25%.

I suggest you rewrite your software as a multi-threaded application, preferably using a language like C or C++.

Comment: you are probably the person who is very close to the problem I got! Yes, indeed, maybe my code is running on a quad core but linode says it's 20 core. Anyway, if its running on a quad core what you said is very right! But see this: if I execute the example code I posted in one tab of my browser and execute it at the same time in another tab. Apache should use 2 cores do that, right? But I still see 24% of cpu usage. Why?

Comment: Good question. The answer is probably because there's still only one PHP application processing these requests. Apparently there's a PHP extension called [pthreads](http://pthreads.org/) that provides it with multi-threading capabilities, but if I was you I'd ditch PHP and start coding something in C. Apache's involvement in all of this is quite small, but the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7116144/1679849) might give you some useful insights.